# Recreating AS3 Color Transformations on server-side JPG

Tags: image, actionscript-3, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

oh wise list,

We need a scalable solution that can handle many concurrent requests for recreating color transformations done on a low-res jpeg in Flash --> a high-resolution jpeg on the server.

I want to create the following process : http://cl.ly/24371N3f0g0W041R380f

Should we send this data to GDLibrary? ImageMagic? and server-side Air app?

or perhaps use C++ libs in the client flash app? and send those to transformation commands to the C++ app on the server to use on the high-res image?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, how crazzy is your color transformation?  Is it just ColorTransform/ColorMatrix?

Image Magic has colorize functions and color transformation functions.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#colorize

- Specify the amount of colorization as a percentage. Separate colorization values can be applied to the red, green, and blue channels of the image with a comma-delimited list of colorization values (e.g., -colorize 0,0,50).

However, this will only get you so far, as this is only the r/g/b multipliers, not the offsets.  For offsets, you'd have to create your own custom function to loop through the libs.  ColorTransform is fairly simple --

it's either: color * multiplier + offset or (color + offset) * multiplier

Stay away from a server side air app -- I would go with a custom already geared towards servers ... ImageMagick, (I personally prefer GMagick, which is the same pretty much)

Comment: re: Color Transformation -- We are just replacing a target color ( with a threshold selection for maximum selection of color range ) with another color ( as per our example ) -- So doing your custom function in ImageMagick would do the trick? thanks!